# How to DoS the Postgres Database

Tags: postgresql, ddos

I am doing small research work on how to protect database against DDoS atack.

I am using postgres database in my testings.
I want to perform a DDoS of Database on my local machine. But I don't really know how to do it.

My plan is to create script that runs bunch of queries. But I want these queries took as much time to complete as possible.

I saw this example: `select tab1 from (select decode(encode(convert(compress(post) using latin1),concat(post,post,post,post)),sha1(concat(post,post,post,post))) as tab1 from table_1)a;`
But I am failing to replicate it in postgres.

I need help in translating this query in postgres or other examples of functions or queries that would take lots of time to complete.

Edit:
sleep functions might not work. They are not loading system enough.

In my understanding, DDoS should be performed with functions that are taking a long time to perform and sucks up tons of compute powers of the system.

Comment: `select pg_sleep(1000000)`

Comment: This query would take a long time to complete indeed, but the problem is that it won't suck up any compute powers of system. (I forgot to add this part)
I do think that it is really very hard to perform DDoS just with "sleep" functions

Comment: create a cross join between huge tables and throw in a group by and order by